# How to read the file name as a string variable after informing the reader the file name should end in the suffix .txt?

Tags: java

Hi I Posted a similar question yesterday, but now I need help with reading the file name as a string variable. Attached is my updated code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class SongWriter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;

        // Scope must be outside the try/catch structure.
        String fileName1;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the file. The file should end in the suffix.txt ");
        fileName1 = keyboard.next();

        try {
            outputStream = new PrintWriter("Song.txt");
            // new FileOutputStream("Song.txt")
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file Song.txt.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("\n classical songs has many lines");
        System.out.println("\nNow enter the three lines of your Song.");
        String line = null;
        //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count;

        for (count = 1; count <= 3; count++) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter line " + count + ": ");
            line = keyboard.nextLine();
            outputStream.println(count + "\t" + line);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        System.out.println("\nYour Song has been written to the file song.txt.\n");
    } // end of main
} // end of class
```

My initial question was how do I Adjust the program so it first asks for a name of the file to write to. Use the Scanner class and its next() method. Read in the file name as a string variable after informing the reader the file name should end in the suffix .txt 
Eg:- Song with the file names Song1.txt,Song2.txt and Song3.txt.
With the help of others I was able  to have the scanner class and the next() in my code. Can someone please tell me why my code is not working?

Comment: What's not working? And what have you declared the `fileName1` variable for?

Comment: _PLEASE_ format your code when you post it here, that is hard to read.

Comment: When I run the programme, I get a prompt asking to Enter the name of the file. The file should end in the suffix.txt. When i enter a name(say song1.txt), the song lines dont get stored in that entered file. Instead it gets stored in the Song.txt file. And also I am unable to enter the first line of the song. It straight away jumps to the second line.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
// Use "Song.txt"
outputStream = new PrintWriter("Song.txt");
```

to

```
// Use the value stored in the fileName1 String.
outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName1);
```

Also, you're not getting the entire line with `keyboard.next()` you should something like this instead

```
fileName1 = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
```

Comment: Hi thanks this works. Now I have a different problem. For some reason, when I enter song.txt or whatever, instead of letting me enter anything on "Enter line 1:," it skips to "the Enter line 2:"prompt. Do you might know why?

Comment: Did you change to `fileName1 = keyboard.nextLine().trim();`

Comment: Hi yes now it works. Thanks a ton! Btw what does trim() do? first i heard it

Comment: [String#trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) creates a copy of the String with leading and trailing white space removed.